# Is there a way to CASE a statement in SQL to satisfy more than two conditions? If not, what is the alternative?

Tags: sql, variables, plsql, case

The logic for thresholds is as follows:

```
High (key=100) and have a score >= 100; 
Medium (key=100 and score >= 150) AND (key=101 and score < 100);    
All other scores are low**
```

Current code that doesn't return the correct results

```
case when a.SCORE_TYPE_KEY = '100' and a.SCORE_NBR >= 100 then 'High'
when (a.SCORE_TYPE_KEY = '100' and a.SCORE_NBR >= 150) AND (a.SCORE_TYPE_KEY = '101' and a.SCORE_NBR < 100) then 'Medium'
else 'Low' END AS Thresholds
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help the rest of the world understand what why the results are not correct.

Comment: Change `...) AND (...` to `OR` for medium. AND does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

you should use OR for medium

```
, case  when a.SCORE_TYPE_KEY = '100' and a.SCORE_NBR >= 100 then 'High'
       when ( (a.SCORE_TYPE_KEY ='100' and a.SCORE_NBR>= 150 ) 
              OR ( a.SCORE_TYPE_KEY='101' and a.SCORE_NBR< 100) ) then 'Medium'              
          else 'Low' END AS Thresholds
```

The same column can't have two different value in  row

Comment: I guess you need to correct this answer as the syntax is not correct.

Comment: I guess you removed the correct line and left the wrong one. Key and score are not columns.

Comment: looking to the OP condition  ..  seems right too me ..anyway  the OP could give us a feedback..

Comment: I mean to say your medium condition are using keywords as `key` and `score` while it must be `SCORE_TYPE_KEY` and `SCORE_NBR`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your case statement needs to be improved as -

```
case when (a.SCORE_TYPE_KEY = '100' and a.SCORE_NBR >= 150)
          OR (a.SCORE_TYPE_KEY = '101' and a.SCORE_NBR < 100) THEN 'Medium'
     when a.SCORE_TYPE_KEY = '100' and a.SCORE_NBR >= 100 THEN 'High'
     ELSE 'Low'
END AS Thresholds
```

Comment: both conditions cannot be met. SCORE_TYPE_KEY cannot be both 100 and 101, not can it be >= 150 and < 100. Plus the case will only give you one result (the first condition it meets), so you won;t get both Medium and Low.